# Enable Auto Assist in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse

A while ago I disabled this feature and now I want to use it again. I went into 
Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist and reenabled the "Enable Auto Activation" .  It is set to a default of 200 ms and the . as the auto activation trigger.  I restarted eclipse and it does not auto assist.  I press the . key after R.layout and nothing happens.  Ctrl +Space says there are no matching templates.  What am I doing wrong so that content assist is not popping up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Java source file in a Source Folder of a Java Project?

Comment: Yes it is in the src folder in a package

Comment: Try going to the Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced preference page and Restoring Defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this in MyEclipse 10. It quit giving me the possible options when I typed "classname.". I reloaded MyEclipse with the "-clean" option (see below) and the problem went away.

e.g. Start>Run "C:\Program Files\Genuitec\MyEclipse 10\myeclipse.exe" -clean